# How to play a sound when words are added into UITextField

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am curious if I can play a sound using MP3 every time a word is added into a `UITextField`. I thought it is interesting. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I guess the problem is the definition of "word". At its simplest, I guess this is "every time the spacebar is pressed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set yourself up as the text field's delegate. Then implement the 
`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method. That method lets you see changes to the field. In that method come up with logic that recognizes that you've entered a new word, and play a sound when it detects a word.

Answer (score 1):

If "the user hit space" is enough for you to consider a word break, then you should assign your view controller to be the delegate of your text field then use code like this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string == " " {
        if let audioURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sound", withExtension: "mp3") {
            do {
                currentSound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL)
                currentSound.play()
            } catch {
                // playback failed for some reason?
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

To make this work you will need to `import AVFoundation` then add a property to your class to store the sound you want to play:

```
var currentSound: AVAudioPlayer!
```